# How to repeat one list to match the length of another?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have two lists:

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
B = ['c', 'a', 't']
```

How could I repeat the items of B to match the length of A?

```
C = ['c', 'a', 't', 'c', 'a']
```

Alternatively, would it also be possible to combine A and B to yield:

```
C = ['ac', 'ba', 'ct', 'dc', 'ea']
```

Comment: How do you define "replace"? What I understand you want to do it removing entries that are not present in both lists. Does order matter for your case?

Comment: What is the logic? Can you break it down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic is unclear, but assuming that you want to repeat the items of `B` as many times as needed to match the length of `A`, use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
B = ['c', 'a', 't']

C = list(islice(cycle(B), len(A)))
```

Output: `['c', 'a', 't', 'c', 'a']`

For fun, another (less efficient) approach but without imports, repeating, then slicing `A`:

```
C = (B*-(-len(A)//len(B)))[:len(A)]

# -(-len(A)//len(B)) is a trick to get the ceiled value of len(A)/len(B)
```

###### combining A and B

```
from itertools import cycle

C = [''.join(x) for x in zip(A, cycle(B))]

# or
C = [f'{a}{b}' for a, b in zip(A, cycle(B))]
```

Output: `['ac', 'ba', 'ct', 'dc', 'ea']`

Comment: @OmarBhai you're welcome, but please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76727816/edit) your question to add details on what you expect exactly. If I had the correct understanding please make it clear. As currently written, there could be other interpretations, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76727883/16343464) in which the values of B and the common values of B and A are concatenated.

Comment: Bro is it possible to get output like C = [ 'ac', 'ba', 'ct', 'dc' ,'ea'], just concatenate B list with A list

Answer (score 3):

To repeat a `list` n times, use `ls * n`.

Example:

```
ls = ['d', 'o', 'g']
ls * 3
```

Output is:

```
['d', 'o', 'g', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'd', 'o', 'g']
```

To add partial repetitions, use slicing to get the last partial repetition and add to full repetitions, you can get the required full repetitions and remainder by using `divmod`:

```
ls = ['s', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'u', 'l', 'a', 'r', 'i', 't', 'y']
n = 24
f, r = divmod(n, len(ls))
ls * f + ls[:r]
```

Output:

```
['s', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'u', 'l', 'a', 'r', 'i', 't', 'y', 's', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'u', 'l', 'a', 'r', 'i', 't', 'y', 's', 'i']
```

You can wrap it in a function so that you can easily reuse it:

```
def repeat(ls, n):
    f, r = divmod(n, len(ls))
    return ls * f + ls[:r]
```

Example usage:

```
In [595]: repeat('Python', 16)
Out[595]: 'PythonPythonPyth'
```

You can also use a list comprehension to do that, just use modular arithmetic to scale down the index when it is greater than or equal to the length of the list:

```
def repeat_listcomp(ls, n):
    l = len(ls)
    return [ls[i%l] for i in range(n)]
```

The first preserves the data type of the argument, the second doesn't.

---

I should add the accepted answer is much more efficient than my list comprehension solution but much slower than my original solution (I mistook the `ns` to `µs`), and my code helps you understand it better:

```
In [598]: %timeit repeat_listcomp('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 2048)
150 µs ± 1.85 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [599]: %timeit repeat('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 2048)
754 ns ± 21.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

In [600]: from itertools import cycle, islice

In [601]: %timeit list(islice(cycle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 2048))
32.9 µs ± 821 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have understand that you want a script which put cat word the len of A list:

It is written in Python.

```py
A = ['a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd' , 'e']

B = ['c' , 'a' , 't']

C = []
C_combine_A_B = []

b_len = len(B)
a_len = len(A)

i = 0
while i < a_len:
    C.append(B[i%b_len])
    C_combine_A_B.append(A[i]+B[i%b_len])
    i+=1

print(C)
print(C_combine_A_B)
```

If you do not understand something tell me and I will explain you.

EDIT: combined list impl added

Answer (score 0):

```
C = B + [x for x in B if x in A]
```

As there's no clear explanation of logic, the most straightforward approach to get desired C list is to concatenate B list with elements of A list that B list contains.

Comment: You might want to add some details on the logic, I hadn't thought of that but this **could** be valid given the absence of explained logic ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use divmod to compute how many times to repeat B and what extra range to add at the end:

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
B = ['c', 'a', 't']

r,x = divmod(len(A),len(B))  # repeats, extra
C   = B*r + B[:x]

print(C)
['c', 'a', 't', 'c', 'a']
```

Another approach could be to use  extend:

```
C = B[:len(A)]
C.extend( C[i] for i in range(len(A)-len(B)) )

print(C)
['c', 'a', 't', 'c', 'a']
```

For your alternate approach, a list comprehension with modulo indexing could do it:

```
C = [a+B[i%len(B)] for i,a in enumerate(A)]

print(C)
['ac', 'ba', 'ct', 'dc', 'ea']
```

or a gnarly map/zip:

```
*C, = map("".join,zip(A,B*(1+len(A)//len(B))))

print(C)
['ac', 'ba', 'ct', 'dc', 'ea']

# or using itertools:

from itertools import cycle
*C, = map("".join,zip(A,cycle(B)))
```